# broom::tidy() with do() in a dplyr workflow fails with a summaryDefault object

Tags: r, broom

I want to do a numerical summary (`summary.default()` in the base package) on a variable in a data.frame and use tidy() in the broom package, but this somehow fails.

In this example, I create a data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep('M', 6), 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F'),
                 val = c(6, 5, NA, NA, 6, 13, NA, 8, 10, 7, 14, 6))
```

I load `plyr` (1.8.3), `dplyr` (0.4.2), and `broom` (0.3.7) (in that order). FYI Running R 3.2.2 on 64-bit Windows, but I get similar issues with 3.2.1 on Unix.

This I think would give me a desirable output:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% do(tidy(summary(.$val)))
```

But I get an error message:

```
Error: corrupt data frame at index 1
```

I can get something desirable using a `plyr` approach with `broom::tidy` as shown below:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% do(summ = summary(.$val)) %>% 
    daply(.(group), function(x) tidy(x$summ[[1]]))

group minimum q1 median mean  q3   maximum <NA>
    F 6       7  8      9.333 11   14      1   
    M 5       6  6.5    7.833 9.25 13      2
```

But obviously I'm asking this question to get to the root of the problem with using `tidy()` (summaryDefault) within the `do()` function as described above.

Comment: `NA`s in `df` are creating problem. If you run this same code after replacing `NA`s with integers, code runs fine.

Comment: Try `df[complete.cases(df),] %>% group_by(group) %>% do(tidy(summary(.$val)))`

Comment: The summaryDefault tidy produces an extra column for NA, so that's still a problem, but thanks @Narendra for narrowing it down

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** this looks like a bug in `broom:::tidy.summaryDefault` (I reported it [here](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom/issues/92)), which assumes that the summary object only has 6 elements (not 7, as is the case when there are `NA` values in the data).  It looks pretty easily fixable but I don't have time right now ...

I used `options(error=recover)` to see where the problem was happening.  Based on what's below, I think the problem has to do with the `"NA"` in the column names, which must be getting evaluated in a non-standard way at some point:

When things break, we are about to do `rbind_all(out[[1]])`.  Here's what we have:

```
 str(out[[1]])
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ minimum: num 6
  ..$ q1     : num 7
  ..$ median : num 8
  ..$ mean   : num 9.33
  ..$ q3     : num 11
  ..$ maximum: num 14
  ..$ NA     : num 1
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ minimum: num 5
  ..$ q1     : num 6
  ..$ median : num 6.5
  ..$ mean   : num 7.83
  ..$ q3     : num 9.25
  ..$ maximum: num 13
  ..$ NA     : num 2
```

If I rename the component data frames, everything is fine:

```
Browse[1]> rbind_all(lapply(out[[1]],setNames,letters[1:7]))
Source: local data frame [2 x 7]

      a     b     c     d     e     f     g
  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1     6     7   8.0 9.333 11.00    14     1
2     5     6   6.5 7.833  9.25    13     2
```

It also works if I rename just the offending column:

```
 ff <- function(x) { names(x)[7] <- ".NA"; x }
Browse[1]> rbind_all(lapply(out[[1]],ff))
Source: local data frame [2 x 7]

  minimum    q1 median  mean    q3 maximum   .NA
    (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)   (dbl) (dbl)
1       6     7    8.0 9.333 11.00      14     1
2       5     6    6.5 7.833  9.25      13     2
```

So the best thing might be to hack/feature request for `broom::tidy` that it specify the `NA` column in some more protected way (`.NA`, `_NA`, `numNA`, ...)

Actually, this looks like a bug in `summaryDefault`.  The contents of that function are

```
ret <- as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(x)))
colnames(ret) <- c("minimum", "q1", "median", "mean", "q3", 
    "maximum")
ret
```

which doesn't take account of the fact that the summary *might* have an `NA's` column in it.  That is, `names(ret)[7]` is an **actual NA value**, not `"NA"` ...